# scanf with more than one delimiter in C

Tags: c, struct, scanf, delimiter

I have a data file with strings, floats, and integers separated by a single comma and a random number of spaces. 
for example:

```
john    , smith ,  3.87 ,  2,  6
```

I would like to scan each value into a struct containing str,str,float,int,int & ignore the commas and spaces. I have figured out up to the float but cant seem to get the intgers. any help would be appreciated my code is as follows:

```
typedef struct applicant {  
char first[15]; 
char last[15];
float gpa;
int grev;
int greq;
} num1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  FILE *in, *out;
  in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
  out = fopen(argv[2], "w");

  num1 class[10];

  int i;

  fscanf(in, "%[^,],%[^,],%f, %d, %d\n", class[i].first, class[i].last, &class[i].gpa, &class[i].grev, &class[i].greq);
  fprintf(out, "%s %s %f %d %d", class[i].first, class[i].last, class[i].gpa, class[i].grev, class[i].greq);
```

Comment: Do you want to read the white space between `john` and the comma to be read into `class[i].first`?

Comment: Use `strtok()` instead.

Comment: what's the output of your fprintf function?

Comment: the random number of spaces is greather than 0?

Comment: why you don't initialize `i`?

Comment: With data like `"Betty Jo  , Smith-Brown,  3.87 ,  2,  6"` what should be saved in `first[]` and `last[]`?

Answer (score 2):

As [sturcotte06](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2584754/sturcotte06) mentioned you should use `strtok()` function alongside with `atoi()` and `atof()` to get the expected result.

```
char text[] = "john    , smith ,  3.87 ,  2,  6";

strcpy(class[i].first, strtok(text, ","));
strcpy(class[i].last, strtok(NULL, ",");
class[i].gpa = atof(strtok(NULL, ","));
class[i].grev = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
class[i].greq) = atoi(strtok(NULL, ","));
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest the following approach.

1. Read the contents of the file line by line.
2. I am assuming the white spaces are not relevant. If that is indeed the case, replace the comma characters with spaces.
3. Use a simpler format to read the data from the line of text to your struct.

Always check the return value of functions that read data from an input stream to make sure that you use the data only if the read operation was successful.

---

```
// Make it big enough for your needs.
#define LINE_SIZE 200

char line[LINE_SIZE];
if ( fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, in) != NULL )
{
   // Replace the commas by white space.
   char* cp = line;
   for ( ; *cp != '\0'; ++cp )
   {
      if ( *cp == ',' )
      {
         *cp = ' ';
      }
   }

   // Now use sscanf to read the data.
   // Always provide width with %s to prevent buffer overflow.
   int n = sscanf(line, "%14s%14s%f%d%d",
                  class[i].first,
                  class[i].last,
                  &class[i].gpa,
                  &class[i].grev,
                  &class[i].greq);

   // Use the data only if sscanf is successful.
   if ( n == 5 )
   {
      // Use the data
   }
}
```